# PHP form won't submit to $_POST

Tags: php, forms, wamp

Noob alert! I am doing Kevin Skoglund's PHP Essentials course on Lynda.com. Ch. 11 is an example to illustrate superglobals. He is using php 5.6 and my WAMP is setup for php 7.0.1. I can't get this simple form to post to the superglobal and I have no idea why.

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $username = $_POST["username"];
       $password = $_POST["password"];
        $message = "Logging in {$username}";
    } else{
        $message= "The form was not submitted";
    }
    ;?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $message;?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <label for="username">Username: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""/>
            <br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""/> <br />
            <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is always null regardless of what is typed into the two fields. Its running from localhost directory, WAMP is live. What  could cause such a simple error?

Comment: Thing is, "how" are you accessing that initial file, as `http://localhost/file.php` or `file:///file.php`? Is a webserver installed and PHP? Is everything running properly? What does HTML source reveal? Same for var_dump().

Comment: where is your form_proc.php file stored?  Is it in the same directory as your index.php file?

Comment: The two files are in the same directory and the url is "http://localhost:63342/Chapter%2004/04_02/Helloworld.php?_ijt=kre3eipmjmea0ls0uor7tb5v7n" which leads to "http://localhost:63342/Chapter%2004/04_02/form_proc.php". Running Apache 2.4.18. I have restarted all services to check if something was wrong in WAMP.

Comment: I've seen this same type of question asked before. As per your link in comments; you're sending as a GET first, why is that? and why the port number?

Comment: I see what you've saying Fred - because of the url. But the form method is to post to the form_proc.php via the superglobal. How would you do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try accessing the form as just `http://localhost/Helloworld.php` then see what that does. If it still doesn't work, then I'm stumped. You can also try doing what I just said here with the URL, but including both the form and the PHP inside the same file and setting the action as `action=""`.

Comment: (The port number came up via PHPstorm I think. Its not something I am setting.) I feel like an idiot asking such a rudimentary question but I really appreciate your help. None of the suggestions have worked Fred.

Comment: I changed the post action to submit to the same form but still no fields were submitted to the $_POST superglobal.

Comment: can you show us the php code that will receive the form values ? that will help us .

Comment: Try running the PHP in the same area that your form is located. So remove `action=""` and just add the PHP at the top of the page. Will this output the keyed entries?

Comment: See revised code, based on all the suggestions. The form output is to $_POST. Thats what the exercise is testing for.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` after your first opening PHP tag. And you have an errant `;` by your closing tag `;?>`

Comment: I ran your exact code in a file called `index_test.php` in my `localhost` directory in XAMPP. It works correctly. So, I cannot duplicate your error. The url was: `http://localhost/index_test.php`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly thanks to everyone who tried to help me. It wasn't the code but in the end the error seems to originate in PHPstorm. When running the php file by having the IDE initiate it there seems to be a port number being added in the localhost address.`http://localhost:63342/www/Helloworld.php?_ijt=6jrieg9npqffa11j0l2k3bv05h`

This is causing the post values to get lost when running the form, and the superglobal comes back empty as a result.

When I initiate localhost directly from WAMP menu and type in the url for the file e.g. `http://localhost/Helloworld.php`, then the code runs as intended. I still have to sort out how to get PHPstorm to run the php files into the correct localhost instance but for now there's a workaround.